# Android Library Package lost the internal interfaces parameters name

Tags: java, android, maven, repository, package

I have a Java class with inside an interface

```
public abstract class ScChecker {

    ...

    public interface CheckerListener {
            void onChangeState(boolean result);
    }

}
```

I had published this on a repository and I recalled this inside another project by the "gradle dependences".

When I try link the listener I find the interface methods param name changed.
I will see only the initial of the variable type "b" and lost "result" param name.

```
checker.setListener(new CheckerListener () {

    @Override
    public onChangeState(boolean b) {
    ...
    }

});
```

> Already check Minify = false